# how overflow occurs differently?

Tags: c

I'm new to C, still struggling in understanding how overflow occurs. Let's say we have the following buggy code to determine whether one string is longer than another:

```
int strlonger(char *s, char *t) {
   return strlen(s) - strlen(t) > 0;  // let's say the first return value of strlen(s) is s1, abd the second is s2
}
```

and we know it is not going to work as the return type of `strlen()` is `size_t` which is `unsigned int`, so when we have sth like `1u - 2u > 0`;the left operand overflows.

I kind of get the idea, it is sth like  `1u - 2u` is -1, but because both s1 and s2 are `unsigned int`, the result should also be `unsigned int`, therefore it overflow.

But considering a different scenario:

```
int a= 1048577;
size_t b = 4096;
long long unsigned c= a* b;
```

since 1048577*4096 = 4294971392 which is out of range of int or unsigned b, so isn't that the result should overflow first? why it is like the result is reserved to keep value just because the left operand c is `long long unsigned` that can hold the value?, isn't that more sensible to make it work only in this way:

```
long long unsigned a= 1048577;
long long unsigned b = 4096;
long long unsigned c= a* b;
```

Comment: Are you sure that `size_t` is `unsigned int` in your compiler?  On 64-bit systems it's typically a 64-bit type, whereas `unsigned int` is usually 32 bits.

Comment: Because the answer to your question is that according to the [usual arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion), the multiplication should be done as `size_t` (assuming it's at least as large as `unsigned int`), and will overflow if the result doesn't fit in `size_t`.  The fact that it's later assigned to `unsigned long long` is indeed irrelevant in that respect.

Comment: `of int or unsigned b` but... `b` is `size_t`, not `unsigned`

Comment: On my system `size_t` is `long unsigned int`, and is 8 bytes. In this case, `a*b` does not overflow (in fact, not even close).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I kind of get the idea, it is sth like 1u - 2u is -1, but because both s1 and s2 are unsigned int, the result should also be unsigned int, therefore it overflow.

Not at all.

The result is whatever type you wish it to be, of course (it can be `double` for all I care), but that result type is not important - or at least it's not of primary importance, because it doesn't affect whether the operation itself is "OK" or not. The operation itself must be defined before you can even begin thinking about converting the result to any type at all (or leaving it in the "natural" type).

What you should focus on is whether an operation such as subtraction on two values of identical unsigned types is defined. And indeed, it always is defined. The C standard states what the result is - and it is very clear that there is no overflow. In fact, it's even clearer: the result **can NEVER overflow**:

> A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type. (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E) §6.2.5/9)

Not only that, but conversions between integers and unsigned integers are well defined as well, and `-1` (of type integer) converts to the maximum value of whatever unsigned type you convert it to. Basically, `-1` converted to unsigned int is a short way of writing `UINT_MAX` etc.

```
unsigned char uc = -1;
assert(uc == UCHAR_MAX);
unsigned short us = -1;
assert(us == USHORT_MAX);
unsigned int ui = -1;
assert(ui == UINT_MAX);
unsigned long ul = -1;
assert(ul == ULONG_MAX);
// etc.
```

> `long long unsigned c= a* b;`
>   since 1048577*4096 = 4294971392 which is out of range of int or unsigned b, so isn't that the result should overflow first?

The C language is simply not designed to interpret it the way you do. That's all. Most decisions in programming language design are completely arbitrary. You might be surprised of course that the designers made a decision different than you'd have made, but both are equally arbitrary.

What happens here is that the whole computation is performed using the `long long unsigned` type, and because it is an unsigned type, it **never** overflows. The C standard says so. And that's all there's to it.

One could argue that doing it the way you propose is worse, because there'd be way more typing to get something that should seem to work. If C worked the way you wanted, you'd need to write your expression as follows:

```
int a = 1048577;
size_t b = 4096;
long long unsigned c = (long long unsigned)a * (long long unsigned)b;
```

One could argue that forcing everyone to pollute their code with endless casts that way would be unkind to say the least. C is nicer than you expect it to be.

Of course C is also full of things that are abhorrent, so you were just lucky that you asked about this and not, say, the millionth question about why `gets()` is bad. The truth is: `gets()` is like Voldermort. You don't say `gets` and you don't use `gets` and everything is fine.